# Why default object's hashCode returns different value in different devices?

Tags: java, android, algorithm, memory, hashcode

By looking at some answers all around SO there seems to be a variety of opinions about what does default `hashCode()` returns on different objects: some say it runs the same algorithm, some say it's memory location based.

Despite those, I've run a few tests where I call the default `myCustomObject.hashCode()` on different Android emulators and it seems that, within each emulator, the `hashCode` is always the same (even after rebooting it) but differs across each one.

Based on this, I'm not sure if it is actually based on an algorithm; or if that algorithm contains some info related to where it runs or even if it's indeed memory based (which this I doubt so, since it will have the same value after rebooting).

Comment: "By looking at some answers all around SO there seems to be a variety of opinions about what does default hashCode() returns" - this really shouldn't be opinion based, rather fact based. Suggest reading the general contract for `Object::hashcode` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you know about `Object`'s `hashCode` is [what the JavaDoc says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()). This part is probably the most relevant:

> As much as is reasonably practical, the hashCode method defined by class Object does return distinct integers for distinct objects. (The hashCode may or may not be implemented as some function of an object's memory address at some point in time.)

So, it's likely to be unique but not guaranteed to be and you can't assume it will be. It may or may not be "some function" of the object's memory location, for any given definition of "memory location," or it could be some ascending number assigned to the object on creation, etc., etc. You don't know without delving into the source code of the JDK/JVM you're using (`hashCode` is a `native` function, so `src.zip` in the JDK doesn't help here), and moreover there's no pragmatic benefit to knowing.

> I'm not sure if it is actually based on an algorithm; or if that algorithm contains some info related to where it runs or even if it's indeed memory based (which this I doubt so, since it will have the same value after rebooting).

It could be an index within the JVM's heap, which with the same program would be in the same place every time.

But again: You don't know, and there's no pragmatic benefit to knowing.